# htaccess conditional for RequestHeader

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

is it possible to have in `.htaccess` (Apache 2.2) a url condition that when met it executes the RequestHeader directive? Something like:

```
if ( %{HTTP_HOST} == "example.com" ){
  RequestHeader unset Set-Cookie
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mod_setenvif` directive for this:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^(www\.)?example\.com$ NO_COOKIE
RequestHeader unset Set-Cookie env=NO_COOKIE
```

Comment: can I use SetEnvIf for targeting specific pages? like enabling cookies only when the url includes the word "cookie"

Comment: Yes sure you can use: `SetEnvIf Request_URI some-page`